Выдаётся ошибка при конвертации .ui в .py
Я использую python 3.12.4 и pyqt5. Смотрел в других источниках решение проблемы, но появлялись иные ошибки. При использовании pyuic5 name.ui -o name.py в cmd (директорию я указывал конечно же) вызывается ряд ошибок:
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "D:\progy\Scripts\pyuic5.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "D:\progy\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'


Такая ошибка возникла с версии PyQt 5.11 - исправляется импортом библиотеки sip (с предварительной установкой через pip install sip):
try:
    from PyQt5 import sip
except ImportError:
    import sip

Другой вариант решения - удалить все возможные библиотеки, связанные с PyQt5, и установить их заново, включая библиотеку PyQt5-sip (до основной PyQt5):
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip uninstall PyQt5-sip
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine

pip install PyQt5-sip
pip install PyQt5


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sip' не находит его

@FellPeredozf добавил 2 вариант - попробуйте его

@FellPeredozf если какой-то из вариантов Вам помог - отметьте ответ как принятый. И если напишите какой именно - скорректирую ответ для других пользователей
